# Capture one character sequence in several groups

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to find in a string all character sequences corresponding to sets of characters.

By instance:

```
re.findall(r"([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)","aa BB cc DD")

return: [('aa', ''), ('', 'BB'), ('cc', ''), ('', 'DD')]
```

So it seems I can use the position in the tuple to determine wich group the string is in.

But it doesn't work when a sequence is in several groups:

```
re.findall(r"([a-z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)","aa bB cc DD")

return: [('aa', ''), ('b', ''), ('', 'B'), ('cc', ''), ('', 'DD')]
```

I would like something like:

```
[('aa', ''), ('b', ''), ('', 'bB'), ('cc', ''), ('', 'DD')]
```

I think it doesn't work because character 'b' is consumed by  "([a-z]+)".nkss

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Switch the order: `([a-zA-Z]+)|([a-z]+)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun it won't help be cause OP want to match the `b` in `cB` in two group

Comment: Ok, you want *overlapping* matches starting at the same position in the string. It is not possible with a mere regex. Or at least you will need a capturing group inside a capturing group. However, I am not sure if that will be quite generic.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I needed a generic solution working for any number of sets of characters. It's probably not possible with regex.